# C GetAsyncKeyState parameters and values

Tags: c

While reading a script on keeping log of which key is pressed on the keyboard (windows platform), I've found the following snippet.
I already have read the msdn document on GetAsyncKeyState() and searched the for explanation but did not find any satisfactory answer.
Thanks in advance 
:)

```
 if (GetAsyncKeyState(character) == -32767){
    //do something
     }
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Did you [read this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646293%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)?

Comment: sorry, just edited... I'm a new comer please check the edited version

Comment: Yes I already have but this -32767 value makes a problem to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `short` (16-bit) value `-32767` is `0x8001` in hexadecimal. This makes it easy to see that bits 0 and 15 are set. The [man page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646293%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) says *"If the most significant bit is set, the key is down, and if the least significant bit is set, the key was pressed after the previous call to GetAsyncKeyState."* As both those bits are set, those two conditions were both true.

Comment: Yes that's the thing I wanted to know ....
and again sorry for the editing time.

Comment: Today is my first day at SO, can't up vote or accept

Comment: oh yes got it bro and thanx 
... you guys are damn cool and helping hands for newbies